# python pandas.Series.isin with case insensitive

Tags: python, pandas, series

I want to filter out some rows with one of DataFrame's column which data is in a list.

```
df[df['column'].isin(mylist)]
```

But I found that it's case sensitive.
Is there any method using ".isin()" with case insensitive?

Answer (score 42, accepted):

One way would be by comparing the lower or upper case of the Series with the same for the list

```
df[df['column'].str.lower().isin([x.lower() for x in mylist])]
```

The advantage here is that we are not saving any changes to the original df or the list making the operation more efficient

Consider this dummy df:

```
    Color   Val
0   Green   1
1   Green   1
2   Red     2
3   Red     2
4   Blue    3
5   Blue    3
```

For the list l:

```
l = ['green', 'BLUE']
```

You can use isin()

```
df[df['Color'].str.lower().isin([x.lower() for x in l])]
```

You get

```
    Color   Val
0   Green   1
1   Green   1
4   Blue    3
5   Blue    3
```

Comment: or, `.isin(map(str.lower, mylist))`

Comment: @JohnGalt, yes. Just that list comprehension is faster than map() and it would matter if the size of the df is large.

Comment: very neat answer! +1

Comment: @MaxU, Thank you:)

Comment: Thank you for this answer. My problem was solved well :)

Answer (score 2):

I prefer to use the general `.apply`

```
myset = set([s.lower() for s in mylist])
df[df['column'].apply(lambda v: v.lower() in myset)]
```

A lookup in a `set` is faster than a lookup in a `list`

Answer (score 1):

Convert it to a `str` using the `str` method and get the lowercase version

```
In [23]: df =pd.DataFrame([['A', 'B', 'C'], ['D', 'E', 6]], columns=['A', 'B', '
    ...: C'])

In [24]: df
Out[24]: 
   A  B  C
0  A  B  C
1  D  E  6

In [25]: df.A
Out[25]: 
0    A
1    D
Name: A, dtype: object

In [26]: df.A.str.lower().isin(['a', 'b', 'c'])
Out[26]: 
0     True
1    False
Name: A, dtype: bool
```

Answer (score 1):

In Pandas version 1.1.0, you can use the [fullmatch](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.str.match.html#pandas.Series.str.match) function with your list converted to `|` conditions. `match` has an option to turn off case-sensitivity.

Example: Consider the dataframe `df` of

```
    Apple   Banana      Orange
0   A       Boy         Cat
1   Ivan    Elephant    Gold
```

`df.Apple.str.lower().isin(['a', 'c', 'd', 'elephant'])` returns the following result:

```
0     True
1    False
Name: Apple, dtype: bool
```

while `df.Banana.str.lower().isin(['a', 'c', 'd', 'elephant'])` returns:

```
0    False
1     True
Name: Banana, dtype: bool
```

### Pandas fullmatch function, with case=False

To achieve the same purpose as above, one can use 
`df.Apple.str.fullmatch('a|c|d|elephant', case=False)` 
and 
`df.Banana.str.fullmatch('a|c|d|elephant', case=False)` 
, which will give the correct results respectively.

```
0     True
1    False
Name: Apple, dtype: bool
```

and

```
0    False
1     True
Name: Banana, dtype: bool
```

Comment: This is a great answer.  Can make a general purpose thing. `mylist=['a', 'b', 'c', 'elephant']` then `df["Apple"].str.fullmatch("|".join(mylist), case=False)`.

Answer (score 0):

I would put my list into a CSV and load it as a dataframe.  Afterwards I would run the command:

```
df_done = df[df["Server Name"].str.lower().isin(df_compare["Computer Name"].str.lower())]
```

This avoids using for loop and can handle large amounts of data easily.

```
df = 5000 rows
df_compare = 1000 rows
```